# Nexus 5 power button does multiple functions

Tags: nexus-5, power-on

The power button on my Nexus 5 also serves to turn up volume and turn on camera. I find this annoying. Is there a way to disable the volume and camera functionality?

Comment: I am aware of double pressing the power button will launch the camera when the phone is locked, but I am surprised to hear that it also turns up the volume. How do you do that?

Comment: Since you asked I've been playing with it, trying to get it happen. It may be that, with the phone in my right hand, thumb on the power button, it happens that my index finger is on the up volume button and pressing with my thumb causes the opposing index finger to press in the up volume. Oops.

Comment: So then, can I disable the camera functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can disable the double tap by setting the option in `Settings->Display->Press power button twice for camera` to off.